# Mix values from 2 dataframes in a mutate function with conditions

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes with these forms:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(
  idCarte = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
  idPack = c('1', '2', '2', '3', '3'),
  timeIn = c('10:00:02', '12:00:50', '11:40:00', '12:10:35', '15:15:00'),
  timeOut = c('12:00:00', '14:00:00', '11:50:00', '15:00:00', '16:00:00')
)

DF1
idCarte  idPack      timeIn   timeOut
      a      1     10:00:02  12:00:00
      a      2     12:00:50  14:00:00
      b      2     11:40:00  11:50:00
      b      3     12:10:35  15:00:00
      b      3     15:15:35  16:00:00
```

```
DF2 <- data.frame(
  idCarte = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
  idPack = c('1', '2', '3', '3', '2'),
  timeBetween = c('11:00:02', '13:00:50', '14:10:35', '15:20:00', '18:00:00')
)

DF2
idCarte  idPack    timeBetween
      a       1       11:00:02
      a       2       13:00:50
      b       3       14:10:35
      b       3       15:20:00
      b       2       18:00:00
```

And I want to get this result

```
idCarte  idPack      timeIn   timeOut  timeBetween
      a      1     10:00:02  12:00:00     11:00:02 
      a      2     12:00:50  14:00:00     13:00:50
      b      2     11:40:00  11:50:00           NA
      b      3     12:10:35  15:00:00     14:10:35
      b      3     15:15:00  16:00:00     15:20:00
```

I can do it with a for loop like this but it's really slow

```
for (i in 1:nrow(DF1)) {
  timeBetweenLocal <- DF2 %>%
    filter(
      idCarte == DF1[i,"idCarte"] &
      idPack == DF1[i,"idPack"] &
      timeBetween >= DF1[i,"timeIn"] &
      timeBetween <= DF1[i,"timeOut"]
    )
  if (nrow(timeBetweenLocal) > 0) {
    DF1[i, "timeBetween"] <- timeBetweenLocal[1, "timeBetween"]
  } else {
    DF1[i, "timeBetween"] <- NA
  }
}
```

I want to do it in a vectorised way with dplyr::mutate to go faster but it seems a little bit tricky.

```
DF1 %>%
  mutate (
    timeBetween = ifelse (
      nrow(DF2 %>%
             dplyr::filter(
               idCarte == .$idCarte &
               idPack == .$idPack &
               timeBetween >=.$timeIn &
               timeBetween <= .$timeOut
             )
      ) > 0,
      DF2 %>%
        dplyr::filter(
          idCarte == .$idCarte &
          idPack == .$idPack &
          timeBetween >=.$timeIn &
          timeBetween <= .$timeOut
        ),
      NA
    )
  )

# Error : Result must have length 4, not 0
```

My problem is that I need test the matching time because there are multiple idCarte, idPack 
Is anyone have an idea to vectorise this algorithm ? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you really need a for loop? Have you tried joining your dataframes and then filter out cases where `timeBetween` is not between `timeIn` and `timeOut`?

Comment: Thank you !
I update my question : new line in DF2.
I think that with this case joining by idCarte and idPack and than filter will make me loose the NA line in the result.
Am I right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with `left_join` and `case_when`. `left_join` can lead to duplicated rows, you can use `na.omit` or `filter(!duplicated(...))` if you want remove some duplications.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# Yours data
DF1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
  idCarte = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
  idPack = c('1', '2', '2', '3', '3'),
  timeIn = c('10:00:02', '12:00:50', '11:40:00', '12:10:35', '15:15:00'),
  timeOut = c('12:00:00', '14:00:00', '11:50:00', '15:00:00', '16:00:00')
)


DF2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
  idCarte = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
  idPack = c('1', '2', '3', '3', '2'),
  timeBetween = c('11:00:02', '13:00:50', '14:10:35', '15:20:00', '18:00:00')
)


# Solution with left_join lead to duplicate rows

df = left_join(x = DF1, y = DF2, by = c("idCarte"="idCarte","idPack"="idPack")) %>% 
  mutate(timeBetween = case_when(hms(timeBetween)>= hms(timeIn) & hms(timeBetween)<= hms(timeOut) ~ timeBetween,
                                  T ~ NA_character_
                                  )
         )

# The output
# 
#   idCarte idPack   timeIn  timeOut timeBetween
# 1       a      1 10:00:02 12:00:00    11:00:02
# 2       a      2 12:00:50 14:00:00    13:00:50
# 3       b      2 11:40:00 11:50:00        <NA>
# 4       b      3 12:10:35 15:00:00    14:10:35
# 5       b      3 12:10:35 15:00:00        <NA>
# 6       b      3 15:15:00 16:00:00        <NA>
# 7       b      3 15:15:00 16:00:00    15:20:00
```

Comment: Thanks works fine !
I complete it with 
`%>%
  arrange(idCarte, idPack, timeBetween) %>%
  distinct(idCarte, idPack, timeIn, timeOut, .keep_all = TRUE)
`
To have the research result.

Comment: Thats great! `distinct()` or `unique()` works well to remove duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Here is the dplyr solution as mentioned in the comments:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

DF1 %>% 
  left_join(DF2) %>% 
  mutate(timeIn = as_datetime(hms(timeIn)),
         timeOut = as_datetime(hms(timeOut)),
         timeBetween = as_datetime(hms(timeBetween))) %>% 
  filter(timeBetween > timeIn & timeBetween < timeOut | is.na(timeBetween))
#Joining, by = c("idCarte", "idPack")
#  idCarte idPack              timeIn             timeOut         timeBetween
#1       a      1 1970-01-01 10:00:02 1970-01-01 12:00:00 1970-01-01 11:00:02
#2       a      2 1970-01-01 12:00:50 1970-01-01 14:00:00 1970-01-01 13:00:50
#3       b      2 1970-01-01 11:40:00 1970-01-01 11:50:00                <NA>
#4       b      3 1970-01-01 12:10:35 1970-01-01 15:00:00 1970-01-01 14:10:35
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I just update DF1 and DF2 in my question (with data.frame creation example this time...) to precise the possible cases.
If there is a idCarte = b and idPack = 2 with a timeBetween outside timeIn timeOut this solution won't works.

Answer (score 0):

To check for matches in the first two columns we may use `outer`. For multiple matches we want to check whether the time is between `timeIn` and `timeOut`. Therefore it's advantageous to convert the times into `POSIXct` format.

```
DF1[3:4] <- lapply(DF1[3:4], as.POSIXct, format="%H:%M:%S")
DF2[3] <- as.POSIXct(DF2[[3]], format="%H:%M:%S")
```

For the `outer` we code a convenience function.

```
rp <- function(x) Reduce(paste, x)
```

Now we create a list `w` with indices which of the first two columns of both data frames do match using `outer`.

```
w <- apply(outer(rp(DF1[1:2]), rp(DF2[1:2]), `==`), 1, which)
```

Look at the `lapply(...` in following line; we call each list entry of `w`, throw either `NA` if it's empty or chose that entry that falls within the time frame of `DF1`. Empty elements we again turn to `NA`. The `do.call("c", ...)` concatenates the resulting list into a vector, that we can `cbind` to `DF1`.

```
res <- cbind(DF1, timeBetween=do.call("c", lapply(seq(w), function(i) {
  r <- DF2[w[[i]], 3]
  if (length(r) == 0) r <- NA
  else r <- r[r > DF1[i, 3] & r < DF1[i, 4]]
  if (length(r) == 0) r <- NA
  return(r)
  })))
```

Optionally, we can strip of the dates at the end.

```
res[3:5] <- lapply(res[3:5], strftime, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

### Result

```
res    
#   idCarte idPack   timeIn  timeOut timeBetween
# 1       a      1 10:00:02 12:00:00    11:00:02
# 2       a      2 12:00:50 14:00:00    13:00:50
# 3       b      2 11:40:00 11:50:00        <NA>
# 4       b      3 12:10:35 15:00:00    14:10:35
# 5       b      3 15:15:00 16:00:00    15:20:00
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just update DF1 and DF2 in my question (with data.frame creation example this time...) to precise the possible cases.
If there is two lines with same idCarte and idPack or one matching idPack/idCarte but with timeBetween out of bounds this solution won't work.

Comment: @amillanfl Ok, that's a bit more complicated. See edit.